# Why new Date() is return a string, but contains more functions?

Tags: javascript, console.log

When execute `new Date()` will return a string look like `Tue Aug 11 2015 14:42:04 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)`

And when I use `typeof new Date()` it will return a `object`, until this point is okey

But why can I not show your attributes and functions in Chrome console, but I can access their?

When I execute:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
```

It will return `Tue Aug 11 2015 14:42:04 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)`, why not `Date {....}` ?

---

@taxicala

I tried create fallowing class:

```
function teste() {
    return 'Hello World';
}

var t = new teste();

typeof t; // "object"
console.log(t); // return 'teste{}'
```

How to can I create a class (function) like `Date()`?

Comment: See here:  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object

Comment: Added to the answer you check the type of a variable by `typeof`. e.g. `typeof new Date()` will return `"object"` and `typeof new Date().toString()` will return `"string"`

Comment: Finally this make sense to me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64530512/how-does-javascript-date-print-out-a-string-when-you-console-log-it

Answer (score 6):

because `console.log` will call `date.toString()`

Answer (score 3):

it is returning a date-object - but everytime you implicitly call it to a string, happening in console.log or when combining with another string the toString() method is called which is returning your String

```
var obj = { toString: function toString() { return 'my object'; } };
```

Comment: to achieve, that your custom-class/object will displayed as readable string, you need to define the toString() method in it....